# Adjust text font size in plotting autofitvariogram in R?

Tags: r, font, graphics, variogram, plot

It should be quite simple to adjust the font size in plotting the outcome of`autofitVariogram` using the **automap** package. The text fonts for the number of pairs are too big; the text fonts for the model, nugget... information are too small and not presentable. I was able to adjust the size of the points, but I failed to adjust the font of the label (or remove them) and the model information.

I've tried:

```
library(automap)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- c("x","y") 
data.auto.variogram <- autofitVariogram(formula = zinc ~1, input_data = meuse)
plot(data.auto.variogram, cex=1, par.settings=list(fontsize=list(text=5),par.main.text=list(cex=3), par.xlab.text=list(cex=2),par.ylab.text=list(cex=2)))
```

But that also reduces the size of the axis label and the information text.

We can use `meuse` as a reproducible example.

Can anyone give some solutions or recommendations please?

[image]

Comment: Use `par.settings` option in the `plot()`.

Comment: I get no errors on the `plot`, but `Error in text.default(data.auto.variogram$exp_var$dist, data.auto.variogram$exp_var$gamma,  : 
  plot.new has not been called yet` on `text(...)`.

Comment: Just tried `plot(data.auto.variogram, par(cex.lab = 0.5))` but turns out `Error in if (plotit) print(vario) else vario : argument is not interpretable as logical`.

Comment: Do not use `par()`. To learn about `par.settings`, searching *xyplot* would be helpful.

Comment: Strange, I tried `plot(data.auto.variogram,par.settings=list(cex.lab = 0.1))` but nothing's changed on the variogram.

Comment: For instance `par.settings=list(fontsize= list(text= 9))` will change base size of the font.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to control the elements separately? If I do that, my axis labels go smaller as well. I just want the label font to be small or disappear. But `par.settings=list(font.lab=list(text=1))` does seem to work.

Comment: In the same `par.settings=list()` you can add `par.xlab.text = list(cex= 1.4)`. (Same applies to `par.ylab.text`). Or `scales=` may be useful as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56428/discussion-between-gorden-jiang-and-kazuhito).

Comment: @Spacedman Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text size of bottom-right annotations is hard-coded in [autokrige.vgm.panel.r](https://github.com/cran/automap/blob/master/R/autokrige.vgm.panel.r), which runs under the hood of **automap**'s `plot()` method. The latter function is also responsible for creating point labels that are passed to `gstat::vgm.panel.xyplot()`, which is hard-coded as well. Now, you might get rid of these point labels through something like

```
## sample data
library(automap)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~ x + y
afv <- autofitVariogram(formula = zinc ~ 1, input_data = meuse)
p <- plot(afv, plotit = FALSE)

## discard point labels
library(lattice)
opts <- trellis.par.get()
opts$add.text$col <- "transparent"
update(p, par.settings = opts)
```

or, similarly, `opts$add.text$cex` to reduce text size. However, this won't affect the bottom-right text section. In order to overcome this limitation, why not just define your own plotting function for objects of class 'autofitVariogram'? Taking inspiration from the source code of [autokrige.vgm.panel.r](https://github.com/cran/automap/blob/master/R/autokrige.vgm.panel.r), this requires little coding efforts and, at the same time, lets you modify the visual appearance of the resulting scatter plot at will.

```
## create custom text annotation
dgt <- function(x) if (x >= 10) 0 else if (x >= 1) 1 else 2

mdl <- afv$var_model
cls <- as.character(mdl[2, "model"])
ngt <- sum(mdl[1, "psill"])
sll <- sum(mdl[, "psill"])
rng <- sum(mdl[, "range"])
lbl <- paste("Model:", cls,
             "\nNugget:", round(ngt, dgt(ngt)),
             "\nSill:", round(sll, dgt(sll)),
             "\nRange:", round(rng, dgt(rng)))

if (cls %in% c("Mat", "Ste")) {
  kpp <- mdl[2, "kappa"]
  lbl <- paste(lbl, "\nKappa:", round(kpp, dgt(kpp)), "")
}

## create plot
xyplot(gamma ~ dist, data = afv$exp_var,
       main = "Experimental variogram and fitted variogram model", 
       xlab = "Distance", ylab = "Semi-variance",
       panel = function(x, y, ...) {
         gstat::vgm.panel.xyplot(x, y, cex = 1.2, ...)
         ltext(max(x), 0.2 * max(y), lbl, font = 2, cex = .9, adj = c(1, 0), 
               col = "grey30")
       }, 
       # arguments required by gstat::vgm.panel.xyplot()
       labels = NULL, mode = "direct", model = mdl, 
       direction = c(afv$exp_var$dir.hor[1], afv$exp_var$dir.ver[1]))
```

[image: variogram]

Comment: Can you explain briefly `dgt <- function(x) if (x >= 10) 0 else if (x >= 1) 1 else 2`?

Comment: Absolutely. `dgt()` lets you control the number of displayed decimal places for nugget, sill, range, and kappa. Values `>= 10` are rounded to the nearest integer; values `>= 1` (but smaller than 10) have one decimal place as seen from kappa above; and smaller values have two decimal places.